# Unity3d c# - Vector3 as default parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, default

How can we add `Vector3` as default parameter for a method? for example:

```
Void SpawnCube(Vector3 p = new Vector3(0,0,0)){...}
```

I just tried the line about I got an error:

> Expression being assigned to optional parameter `p' must be a constant or default value

I want to customise a function to spawn some `game objects` that if I did not provide the `transform.position`, it will go to `(0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the general case, you can't. The default arguments are somewhat limited. See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition. If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used. A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

In the specific case you posted however, I suspect that `new Vector3()` will be equivelent to `new Vector3(0,0,0)`, so you may be able to use that instead.

If you need a non-zero default value, you may be able to use [method overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: You can. See my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420932/8512294

Comment: Using the default constructor is covered by my original answer above...

Comment: Oh yes, so it does. I must have stopped reading after "You can't"

Answer (score 32):

I know this is already answered but I just want to add other ways to do this. `Vector3? p` and `Vector3 bar = default(Vector3)` should do it.

```
public void SpawnCube(Vector3? p = null)
{
    if (p == null)
    {
        p = Vector3.zero; //Set your default value here (0,0,0)
    }

}
```

As [htmlcoderexe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294216/unity3d-c-sharp-vector3-as-default-parameter/30294572?noredirect=1#comment79027829_30294572)  pointed out,

To use `p`, you have to use `p.Value` or cast the `p` back to `Vector3` with `((Vector3)p)`.

For example, to access the `x` value from this function with the `p` variable, `p.Value.x`, or `((Vector3)p).x`.

---

**OR**

```
public void SpawnCube(Vector3 bar = default(Vector3))
{
    //it will make default value to be 0,0,0
}
```

Comment: Do that means if I did not put in any value, it will go to `Vector3(0,0,0)`?

Comment: yes. try it yourself with debug.log and call the function without passing it any value.

Comment: If you go with ``Vector3?``, you'll need to cast it or use ``p.Value``, otherwise you get a type error.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have modified my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Another way to get back to a `Vector3` from a `Vector3?` is like: `Vector3 bar = foo ?? Vector3.zero` where Vector3.zero is what will be used if it's null.

Comment: The 2nd option can also be reduced to `Vector3 bar = default`

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround You can overload method.

**INSTEAD THIS**

```
void SpawnCube(Vector3 p = new Vector3(0,0,0)){...}
```

**USE THIS**

```
void SpawnCube(Vector3 p)
{
  //Implementation
}

//overloaded method without parameter which calls SpawnCube with given default parameter
void SpawnCube()
{
  SpawnCube(new Vector3(0,0,0));
}
```

You've got one implementation of `SpawnCube` method body and you can use it with or without parameter :)

Answer (score 6):

Hi I just ran into this issue where I needed the Vector3 to be optional. But it would keep saying i need a compile time constant. To get around this issue I used this :

```
    public void myMethod(Vector3 optionalVector3 = new Vector3())
    {
        //you method code here...
    }
```